# How does pointer incrementation work?

Tags: c, pointers

We have an array: `int p[100]`. 
Why `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p+i)` and not `*(p+i*sizeof(int))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why p[i] is equivalent to *(p+i) and not *(p+i*sizeof(int)) ?

Because some processor architectures cannot dereference a pointer that does not point to an address that is aligned by the size of its type. That basicly means that a pointer to a 
   4 byte integer should always point to an adress that is the multiple of 4.

When a program tries to dereference a misaligned pointer it might cause a "Bus error". You can read more about it [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error).

What you are asking for is that `p + 1` should increment the pointer by one byte instead of one element. If the language was designed that way writing `p++` would no longer be valid for pointers of other types than `char`. It would also cause big problems with pointer alignment when a programmer forgets to write `* sizeof(*p)` to make the addition.

It might be confusing but there are very valid reasons for why the language was designed this way.

Answer (score 7):

> Why p[i] is equivalent to `*(p+i)`  and not `*(p+i*sizeof(int))` ?

Because `*(p+i)` is also the same as `*((int *) ((char *) p + i * sizeof (int)))`. When you add an integer `i` to a pointer, the pointer is moved `i` times the size of the pointed object.

Answer (score 1):

This is because before adding `i` to `p` compiler calculates internally the size of data type `p` points to and then add it `i` times to `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Array elements are stored contiguously.

```
*(p+i)
```

Here p has the base address of array p and i ranges from 0 to 99.

So you can iterate over the elements of *p* by incrementing *i*.

Answer (score 0):

> Why p[i] is equivalent to `*(p+i)` and not `*(p+i*sizeof(int))`?

This is because of the way pointer arithmetics work: adding an integer `n` to a pointer yields a pointer to the `n`th *element* (not byte) from the first on (0-based).