# How do pointers know the underlying size of an item?

Tags: c, pointers

As asked in "[How does pointer incrementation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730511/how-does-pointer-incrementation-work)", I have a follow-up question.

How does a pointer know the underlying size of the data it points to? Do pointers store a size of the underlying type so they can know how to increment?

I'd expect that the following code would move a pointer forward one byte:

```
int intarr[] = { ... };
int *intptr = intarr;
intptr = intptr + 1;
printf("intarr[1] = %d\n", *intptr);
```

According to the accepted answer on the linked site, having a pointer increment by bytes and not by the underlying `sizeof` the pointed element would cause mass hysteria, confusion, and chaos.

While I understand that this would probably be an inevitable outcome, I still don't understand how pointers work in this regard. Couldn't I declare a `void` pointer to some `struct[]` type array, and if I did so, how would the `void` pointer know to increment by `sizeof(struct mytype)`?

---

Edit: I believe that I've worked most of the difficulties out that I'm having, but I'm not quite there as far as demonstrating it in code.

See here: http://codepad.org/0d8veP4K

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int intarr[] = { 0, 5, 10 };
    int *intptr = intarr;

    // get the value where the pointer points
    printf("intptr(%p): %d\n", intptr, *intptr);
    printf("intptr(%p): %d\n", intptr + 1, *(intptr + 1));
    printf("intptr(%p): %d\n", intptr + 2, *(intptr + 2));

    // the difference between the pointer value should be same as sizeof(int)
    printf("intptr[0]: %p | intptr[1]: %p | difference: %d | expected: %d",
        intptr, intptr + 1, (intptr + 1) - intptr, sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do *you*  know what kind of pointer `intptr` is? (Hint: It's the declaration. The compiler has access to the declaration. The compiler *knows*).

Comment: You know that a pointer points to the beginning of a memory block containing your data. If you have a void pointer and you cast it to `struct mytype` it will effectively access that memory block, because it occupies `sizeof(struct mytype)`

Comment: So how does the compiler define these things in memory? Does it rewrite my `*(intptr + 1)` to be `*(intptr + 1 * sizeof(int))`?

Comment: You cannot increment a void pointer. C is a statically typed language. Every type is known at compile time. Therefore sizeof any type is also known at compile time.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay yes, but it doesn't re-write the C code, it implements the pointer arithmetic as required by the data type size. That's why arithmetic on `void*` pointers cannot work: the size of the data pointed to is unknown.

Comment: @this VLAs are an exception to "sizeof any type is also known at compile time".

Comment: Your comments suggest your mental model of "pointer" is some sort of integer.  If you instead use the mental model of "thing that points at objects of a certain type" , then it seems natural that "+1" means "point to the next object".

Comment: Okay, I've added a code example to explain how I'm trying to understand the underlying nature of things.

Comment: Your added example is almost there: but when subtracting pointers the same applies: it considers the data type. That's why subtracting pointers to adjacent elements of `int` array gives `1` and not `4`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you submit an answer with the corrected code and a fuller explanation of how the the compiler does things?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay the two faults I see with your code are a) what you "expect" and b) if you use the `%p` format specifier you should technically cast the pointer as in `printf("%p", (void*)myptr)`. As for the pointer arithmetic, it works the same way as array indexing does, where `array[index+1]` moves to the next array element. You know - in that case you don't write `array[ index + sizeof(array[0]) ]` do you?

Comment: It is VERY COMMON that the difference between the address of subsequent elements in an `int` array is the same as the value of `sizeof(int)`.  Yet this is not specified to be so in C.  The `sizeof()` returns the size in `char` of an object. Yet different types may "live" in different address spaces and `int` may live in 4-byte land while `char` lives in 1-byte land.  In 4-byte land, the value of the `int *` may only need to increment by 1 to get to the next `int`.

Comment: Note the the type returned from `sizeof()` and pointer subtraction may be incompatible with `int`.  Could use `printf("intptr[0]: %p | intptr[1]: %p | difference: %td | expected: %zu", (void *) intptr, (void *) (intptr + 1), (intptr + 1) - intptr, sizeof(int));`

Comment: @chux subtracting the addresses of two adjacent ints always gives `1`.  I guess you are talking about the possibility of unusual mappings when converting between pointers and integer types.

Comment: Close, The comment was not on the value of `1`, but on its type, being a pointer difference: `ptrdiff_t` (which is the signed integer type of the result of subtracting two pointers) which needs a printf specifier of `%td`.  Similar for `sizeof(int)` --> ``"%zu"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do pointers store a size of the underlying type so they can know how to increment?

This question suggests that type information needs to be kept with the object at runtime to make correct decisions on how to perform the correct operations for the type. That's not true. Type information becomes part of the *code*.

It may be easier to understand if we add a third type into the mix: floating point.

Consider this sample program:

```
int a,b,c;
float x,y,z;

void f(void)
{
  c = a+b*3;
  z = x+y*3;
}
```

(I ask you to think about the `float` vs. `int` case first not because it's simpler but because it's more complex. The extra complexity prevents you from taking shortcuts that are tempting but wrong.)

The compiler must translate `f` into some assembly code that performs two different kinds of addition and multiplication. Although the same operators (`+` and `*`) appear twice in the C code, the assembly code won't look so symmetric. The first half will use the processor's integer registers, integer addition instruction, and integer multiplication instruction, and the second half will use floating point registers, floating point addition, and floating point multiplication. Even the constant `3` will be represented differently in the two places it appears.

At the assembly level, the memory where `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`, and `z` are stored doesn't need to be tagged because the type information is implicit in the instructions that access that memory. The loads and stores of the integer registers will only be targeted at the memory locations holding `a`, `b`, and `c`.

The C arithmetic operators are overloaded. When translating from a language with an overloaded operator to a language without a corresponding overloaded operator, the type information from the first language becomes part of the name of the operator in the second language. ("Name mangling" when translating from C++ to C is the same thing happening at another level. You could say that assembly language "ADD" (integer) and "FADD" (floating point) instructions are name-mangled `+` operators.)

Now, about pointer arithmetic. Pointers are just another type to overload. If the expression `a=a+1` can generate two different varieties of assembly code depending on whether `a` is `int` or `float`, why not a third variety when `a` is `int *`, another when `a` is `struct tm *`, and so on?

In the C code, type information is contained in the variable declarations. In the compiler's intermediate representation, the type of every expression is known. In the compiler's output, the necessary pieces of type information are implicit in the machine instructions.

Answer (score 5):

It is in the type declaration.  `p1` knows the size of the type because it is `sizeof(*p1)` or `sizeof(int)`.  `p2` does not know as `sizeof(void)` is not defined.

```
int *p1; 
void *p2;

p1++;  // OK
p2++;  // Not defined behavior in C
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a crude answer, but it's worth noting at the machine level that data types, as we know them in C, *don't exist*. We might have arithmetical instructions that operate on integers stored in some general-purpose register, e.g., but there's nothing stored to identify that the contents of some register is actually an `int`. All the machine sees is a bunch of bits and bytes in various types of memory.

So you might even wonder how it's possible for a compiler to know how to do this:

`int z = x + y;`

How can it know to do an integer addition here if there's nothing stored when the program is running to identify that the memory regions storing the contents of `x` and `y` and `z` are `ints`?

And the short/crude answer is that the machine doesn't know once the program is running. Yet it had this information available when it generated the instructions that would be used to run the program.

It's the same case with pointers:

```
int intarr[] = { ... };
int *intptr = intarr;
```

Doing something like `intptr + 1` here can be done to increment the pointer address by `sizeof(int)`. The compiler knows to do this based on the information provided by you, the programmer, in this C code. If you did this instead:

```
int intarr[] = { ... };
void *voidptr = intarr;
```

... then trying to perform any arithmetic on `voidptr` would result in an error, since we aren't giving the information necessary for the compiler to know what machine instructions to generate.

> Couldn't I declare a void pointer to some struct[] type array, and if
>   I did so, how would the void pointer know to increment by
>   `sizeof(struct mytype)`?

It can't. The void pointer would equate to a loss of compile-time information that would prevent the compiler from being able to generate the appropriate instructions. If you don't provide the info, the compiler doesn't know how to do the pointer arithmetic. And this is why functions which accept a void pointer like `memcpy` need a byte size to be specified. The pointee contents don't provide that kind of info, only the programmer can provide it since this kind of information is not stored in the memory used by the program at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful and helpful in understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

in your example:

- sizeof(pointer) is 4 bytes
- sizeof(int) is 4 bytes

and in your program

```
   Output:
    intptr(0xffcbf5dc): 0
    intptr(0xffcbf5e0): 5
    intptr(0xffcbf5e4): 10
    intptr[0]: 0xffcbf5dc | intptr[1]: 0xffcbf5e0 | difference: 1 | expected: 4
```

and if you try: 0xffcbf5e0 - 0xffcbf5dc = 4 (hex sub)and this is the sizeof(int).

- about using void*: you can use the void*
- about your structure :you can make sizeof(yourStructre)